# Find if character is an ASCII character in Groovy

Tags: groovy, ascii

How can I determine if char is a part of ASCII in Groovy / Grails. Is there any standard function or do I have to write my own?

Comment: Any character < 128 is an ASCII character. What exactly are you trying to find out? Why do you care if a character is present in ASCII? This sounds like [a XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Groovy:

```
    int code = (int)"A"
    0 <= code && code <= 127
```

Answer (score 4):

And if you want to find out if an entire String can be encoded as ASCII, you can do:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset
assert Charset.forName("US-ASCII").newEncoder().canEncode( 'tim_yates' )
```

Comment: In Java 7 and up you can use [`StandardCharsets.US_ASCII`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#US_ASCII) instead of `Charset.forName()`.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII characters are (in Unicode) characters 0 to 127 (ASCII was 7 bits), so check it's charcode.
If you only want printable character codes use 32 to 126.

```
assert 'a' as char >= 0 && 'a' as char <= 127
```